# Can you rearrange the vertices of a simple graph to determine if it is planar?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can you rearrange the vertices of a simple graph to determine if it is planar?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your first picture is $K_{3,3}$ with partite sets $\{a,d,f\}$ and $\{b,c,e\}$. It is well known to be non-planar.

In your second drawing, edge $bd$ is drawn twice and edge $de$ is missing.

So clearly mistakes have been made when you moved things around.

However if you start with a non-planar graph (which you did), it is impossible to reposition vertices and/or edges in any way and make it planar.